# JQuery: Swap image src with link name on rollover

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, swap, src

Here's the setup that I'm hitting a wall with. I've got a long list of links that I want to all give the same class.

To the right, on the page, is an image whose src I want to change out when these links are rolled over. I figured the easiest way to do this would be to store the new img src into a "name" attribute on the links. When the link is rolled over, the JQuery takes the links "name" and replaces the img "src" with it.

I was turned on to this bit of code here but for the life of me I cannot get it functional. Below is also a rough setup of the page.

```
$('.nav_tradeshow').mouseover(function(){
    var a = $(this).attr('name');
    var b = $("#submenuImage1").attr('src');
    $("#submenuImage1").attr('src', b).attr('name', a);
});


<a href"#" class="nav_tradeshow" name="images/newimage.jpg">Link One</a>
<a href"#" class="nav_tradeshow" name="images/newimage.jpg">Link Two</a>
<a href"#" class="nav_tradeshow" name="images/newimage.jpg">Link Three</a>
<a href"#" class="nav_tradeshow" name="images/newimage.jpg">Link Four</a>
<a href"#" class="nav_tradeshow" name="images/newimage.jpg">Link Five</a>

<img id="submenuImage1" src="images/oldimage.jpg" />
```

Comment: Use data attributes, don't use the name attribute to store random URL's

Comment: And you're changing the source of the anchors, which don't have a src attribute, as `this` is the currently hovered anchor element ?

Comment: Sorry, that 2nd (this) was incorrect. It's actually set to the image ID.

Answer (score 1):

Store the original source inside the image element itself using [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/). Use [`jQuery.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function to assign mouseenter and mouseleave events simultaneously. And I would suggest that you use HTML5 data attributes to store URLs instead of `name` attribute:

```js
$(function() {
  var $image = $("#submenuImage1");
  $image.data("old-src", $image.attr("src"));
  $(".nav_tradeshow").hover(function() {
    $image.attr("src", $(this).data("image-src"));
  }, function() {
    $image.attr("src", $image.data("old-src"));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="nav_tradeshow" data-image-src="//lorempixel.com/200/200/food/1/">Link One</a>
<a href="#" class="nav_tradeshow" data-image-src="//lorempixel.com/200/200/food/2/">Link Two</a>
<a href="#" class="nav_tradeshow" data-image-src="//lorempixel.com/200/200/food/3/">Link Three</a>
<a href="#" class="nav_tradeshow" data-image-src="//lorempixel.com/200/200/food/4/">Link Four</a>
<a href="#" class="nav_tradeshow" data-image-src="//lorempixel.com/200/200/food/5/">Link Five</a>

<img id="submenuImage1" src="//lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1/" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the wrong attribute. Just change from

```
$("#submenuImage1").attr('src', b).attr('name', a);
```

to

```
  $("#submenuImage1").attr('src', a);
```

It's also a good idea change the adribute from **name** to **data-name**. So it will be following the W3C Standards

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#submenuImage1").attr
({
'src': b,
'name': a
});
```